Intelli sense for Jasmine stopped working in VSCode
Yesterday, hovering expect and other jasmine functions gave me suggestions. Today, it does not. I tried restarting and updating, it is still a problem.
I found this question, which suggest it should work out of the box: Intellisense not working with Jasmine on VS Code
I have jasmine installed in node modules and in package.json:
  "scripts": {
    "unittest": "jasmine --config=jasmine_unit.json --parallel=14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/pg": "^8.6.5",
    "jasmine": "^5.1.0"
  }

Running it works, I run it like this:
npm run unittest

It did, until today? How can I resolve this and get it working again? I am new to using jasmine so not knowing what functions are available is particularly annoying.
Is there at least workaround by importing the symbols explicitly?

Are you using TypeScript? I would look into tsconfig.json and tsconfig.spec.json files to include the types: ["jasmine", "node"] in the compilerOptions.
